# How can i filter dataframe if data type is tuple?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, for some reason, the data type of this dataframe is tuple.

Let me list an example:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))
In [15]: df[3] = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (1,2), (-1, 1)]
In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
    0   1   2        3   4
0   0   1   2   (1, 2)   4
1   5   6   7   (2, 3)   9
2  10  11  12   (4, 5)  14
3  15  16  17   (1, 2)  19
4  20  21  22  (-1, 1)  24
```

i want to keep those lines who's first element > 1

which means, the expected result is:

```
In [20]: df.loc[[1, 2]]
Out[20]: 
    0   1   2       3   4
1   5   6   7  (2, 3)   9
2  10  11  12  (4, 5)  14
```

is there any good methods?

Comment: Try: ``df.loc[df[3].str[0] > 1]``

Comment: @sammywemmy's comment is the right way to do this. Fastest and cleanest. Also, despite the naming of `.str` method, in that case `df[3].str[0].dtypes` is in fact `int64`, so the comparison is correct and very fast. Please post it as an answer. It is the correct one.

Comment: BTW, side note, I often use `df.applymap(type)` to inspect the actual type of all the cells (especially for the columns that just show up as `'object'` in `df.dtypes`). In this example, you can verify that all values of col 3 are tuples with `(df.applymap(type) == tuple).all()[3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pandas.Series.str.get](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) can access elements from lists,tuples and is not limited to just strings:

```
df.loc[df[3].str[0] > 1]

    0   1   2     3     4
1   5   6   7   (2, 3)  9
2   10  11  12  (4, 5)  14
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pandas.DataFrame.aggregate() with lambda function as argument .This will return the first element of tuple.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))
df[3] = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5), (1,2), (-1, 1)]
df1=df[df[3].aggregate(lambda x:x[0])>1]
print(df1)
```